# Getting Bad request while posting form-url-encoded data with Feign client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Response : {"httpCode":"400","httpMessage":"Bad Request","moreInformation":"One or more required API parameters are missing in the API request."}

From the logs i can see all params are passed as below
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=abcd&client_id=sample&client_secret=sample

```
@FeignClient(name = "tru", url = "${api.tru.url}", configuration = TruConfig.class)
public interface TruClient {
    @PostMapping(value = "/tru/oauth2/token", consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    AuthTokenResponse getAccessToken(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, ?> formParams);

     class FeignSupportConfig {

        @Autowired
        private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

         @Bean
         public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
             return new FormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "scope" is unnecessary.
see this documentation here https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-client-credentials-flow
your parameters should be like this

```
"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&audience=YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER"
```

Comment: Did you test without "scope"??
Because I didn't see that field in any documentation
Did you use a custom authorization server?

Comment: Yes. this is custom auth server by third party